# Parsing JSON like data interchange format

Tags: php, json, data-structures, standards

I'd like to use a data interchange format that uses no quotation marks. Maybe something based on JSON:

```
{
  param: value,
  param: value,
  param: {
    [{
      param: value,
      param: value
    }, {
      param: value,
      param: value
    }]
  }
}
```

How should I go about parsing something like that in let's say PHP. Should do it through regular expressions?

Comment: What's wrong with quotation marks?

Comment: This sounds like the problem isn't quotation marks, instead it's some code (probably regex-based) that barfs on them. I would suggest to fix the broken code, instead of trying to shoehorn a different data format in there to cover up the problem.

Comment: What will you do if your value contains commas?

Comment: Looking at the edited version (in particular, "Should do it through regular expressions?"), I feel my guess has been confirmed.

Comment: There is json5, that names without quotes, comments, multiline strings, but string "values" still need quotes. https://github.com/colinodell/json5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use JSON and leverage off the available libraries and tools available to you ? [This blog entry](http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/10/creating-parsing-json-data-php.html) details a JSON parser in PHP.

> To handle JSON data there is JSON
>   extension in PHP which is available
>   after PHP 5.2.0. Two functions :
>   json_encode()  and json_decode()  are
>   very useful converting and parsing
>   JSON data through PHP.

Creating another format seems repetitive and error prone when there are so many well-defined and well-tested options available (JSON, XML, Google Protocol Buffers, YAML).

Comment: I know, and I still make the argument that it's a poor design decision. Perhaps there's a *good* reason to avoid these, but it's not been expressed.

Comment: You're quite right, but it doesn't answer the question as asked.

Comment: That's a favorite trick of mine on StackOverflow, I confess. Sometimes the question being asked isn't the real question

Comment: Similarly, "Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML" generally doesn't answer the question as asked. It's still the right answer, though.

Comment: I'm not saying that you shouldn't have done it; I've given similar answers myself.  I'm just pointing it out.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I should figure out a way to use a standard format. Thanks for the prompt and thoughtful responses.

Answer (score 2):

What's so important about having your format not use quotation marks? Chances are there's something else you could change to make that requirement go away (which would be better).

As far as using regular expressions to parse JSON-like formats, *no*. This is a **BAD** idea; regular expressions were never really intended to parse recursive structures like JSON. At the very least you'll run into issues with performance of the many regex matches you'll need to use to attempt to deal with recursion; at worst you'll run into snafus of attempting to even sort out how to match and parse recursion in the first place.

Your format as proposed has its own issues, as well: how do you differentiate between a `,`, `{`, or `:` in the value of a key, and the actual `,`, `{`, or `:` that's part of the format? How do you deal with spaces in key or value names?

Answer (score 1):

You could use XML and not use any attributes.  You'd also need to avoid the header, which has some quotation marks.